# Pigeon Hole Principle for a triangle

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Within, an equilateral triangle whose length of each side is 200 meters. Five metropolitan police officers guard the garden taking a position as far away from each other as possible to cover more. Using the Pigeon-Hole Principle, explain how with five police officers, there are always two police officers within 100 meters of each other. You may use a picture to support your proof. You may also assume the following theorems are true.

- The line segment in a triangle joining the midpoint of two sides of the triangle is said to be parallel to its third side and is also half of the length of the third side.
- The distance between two points inside an equilateral triangle is less than the side of the triangle.

What I have tried: depending on the two theorems I have, there are four parts but even if 5 officers falls like this and 2 of them are near, I dont get how it is possible tbat there's only 2 of them that falls near and not 3? Shouldn't the one adjacent to both of them be near too?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried drawing a picture with the midpoint-joining lines mentioned in the given theorems? What do you see?

Comment: yes, I edited my question for what i was actually asking.

Comment: If I understand correctly what you wrote in your edit, it seems like you misunderstood the problem. It asks you to prove that you can always find *at least one pair* of police officers who are near enough, it is *not* required that *exactly one pair* of police officers are near, while all the other pairs are far from each other. They could all stand a meter apart and it would be fine. What's not fine is if all of them are more than 100 meters from everyone else. You are tasked to prove that's never the case.

Comment: First you have to prove that two of them are near, than you can think about a third one. How do you prove that at least to of them have a  distance less than 100 metres?

Comment: Right, Got it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For each pair of sides, join their midpoints to each other by a line segment. This makes four sub-triangles, which are the pigeon holes, and the five police officers are the pigeons. Use the two facts you are given.

Comment: @user2661923  One of the facts user is allowed to assume is "the distance between two points inside an equilateral triangle is less than a side of the triangle." The only situations not covered by this is if one (or both) points are on an edge of the triangle. In such a case if say P is on an edge and Q is not, the segment PQ could be moved a bit until both ends are strictly inside the triangle. If both P and Q are on the same edge it is clear, and if P say on edge AB and Q on edge AC [A,B,C vertices of the triangle] the segment can be moved parallel to itself so endpoints P,Q inside.

Comment: You are right, and I have deleted my comment.  Once again, I was careless in reading the original question.

Comment: @user2661923 But your comment was correct since the thing given in OP's post only covers two points inside, but not on the boundary of, the equilateral triangle. That can be rectified as in my comment above, by reducing to the case with both points strictly inside the triangle.